# Freemarker :traverse map collection and key values are xpath dom

Tags: freemarker

Here are my XML profile:test.xml

```
<meta>
  <view id="FirstView">
     <table id="father">
        <overwrite colid="HAHA"/>
        <overwrite colid="LALA"/>
        <overwrite colid="WAWA"/>
     </table>
  </view>
</meta>
```

And this is my datasource profile:datasource.xml

```
<meta>
  <table id="ProtoTable">
     <column id="PROTOID" name="protoID"/>
     <column id="HAHA"  name="HAHA"/>
     <column id="LALA"  name="LALA"/>
     <column id="WAWA"  name="WAWA"/>
  </table>
</meta>
```

Now I have a collection like List : dataCollection
I need to overwrite the prototable's columns 
My ftl file:

```
<#list dataCollection as dc>
  <#list Prototable.meta.table[1].column as col>
    <#list test.meta.view.table[1].overwrite as ow>
       <#if col.@id == ow.@colid>
            ***${dc[col.@id]}***
       </#if>
    </#list>
  </#list>
</#list>
```

It says that the line "${dc[col.@id]}"  is null or missing.
I do not know why. I can print "${col.@id}" ,it isn't null.
I am a newcomer in freemarker,please forgive my poor English. Thank you very much~!

Comment: The format of dataCollection is like "List<map>"

Comment: Well, it says that `dc` has no such item, like `dc.HAHA` or like. Does it have it?